# How to show Soft keyboard when user click the textBox

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Newbie to UWP, How to show keyboard when user click the textBox?

I use the below and I don't see the Soft Keyboard pop up when user click the textBox.

I am using Vs2015 community version with Win 10 OS PC

```
<TextBox InputScope="EmailSmtpAddress" />
```

How to

1. Just pop up a keyboard to enter text by user without InputScope and with InputScope?
2. How to disappear the keyboard when use tap anywhere on the screen?

Would appreciate if you can provide some links of tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: Are you targeting mobile or this is for PC? Not sure if the soft keyboard shows, if you have standard one connected to device. You can always try to show/hide it manually.

Comment: For tablet mode and Mobile Keyboard shows automatically.

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about this unless you created a TextBox from scratch. Otherwise that UWP control automatically displays it on devices that require it.

Comment: @Anthony, I dont have a Surface Tablet. I am using win10 -PC for testing. Will the keyboard cover the TextBoxes??? Where the keyboard is positioned? Bottom ? Center ?